# UWP setting image from REST response

Tags: asynchronous, uwp

I'm going to asynchronously call a REST endpoint, which will respond with a base64 image.  How can I set an image in my UWP application to display the returned image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a base64 string to a byte array and then convert the image. I wrote a method that might help you.

```cs
public async static Task<BitmapImage> Base64ToImg(string b)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(b))
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"^data:(.*?)base64,");
        string source = regex.Replace(b, "");
        var bt = Convert.FromBase64String(source);
        var image = bt.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();
        var result = new BitmapImage();
        await result.SetSourceAsync(image);
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```cs
string webBase64 = await GetBase64FromWeb();
var imageSource = await Base64ToImg(webBase64);
ImageControl.Source = imageSource;
```

Best regards.